# Filling a box with cubes sized as powers of 2 with as few boxes as possible

Tags: geometry, discrete-optimization, tiling

Say I have a box with integer dimensions and I need to fill it with cubes with side lengths of power of 2, how can I fully fill the box with as few cubes as possible? So say i have a $5 \times 5 \times 9$ box, how do I fill the space with as few cubes as possible (options would in this case include cubes with side length: 1,2,4). I'm looking for a general explanation, not just the answer to this example

Comment: I doubt you can do better than the obvious - two $4\times 4\times 4$ cubes and then the rest $1\times 1\times 1$ cubes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I expanded it to refer to more than just the example

Comment: That is assumes. I’m just giving my intuition, but obviously you want a general formula.

Comment: The simplest guess is, if the box is $a\times b\times c,$ with $a\leq b\leq c,$ and $2^k\leq a<2^{k+1},$ is to take a $2^k$ cube out of the corner, and treat the remainder as three separate boxes, a $a\times b\times(c-2^k)$ box, an $a\times (b-2^k)\times  2^k$ box, and an $(a-2^k)\times 2^k\times2^k$ box. All my intuition says this will be the best you can do. This gives a recursion. But I can’t prove it just yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this as a set partitioning problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $\ell$, $w$, and $h$ be the dimensions of the box.  Let $C$ be the set of all possible cubes that have a side length that is a power of $2$ and can fit in the box.  Let $C_{i,j,k}\subset C$ be the set of cubes that contain cell $(i,j,k)\in [\ell] \times [w] \times [h]$.  For $c\in C$, let binary decision variable $x_c$ indicate whether cube $c$ is used.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{c\in C} x_c$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{c\in C_{i,j,k}} x_c = 1 \quad \text{for all $(i,j,k) \in [\ell] \times [w] \times [h]$}$$
that force each unit cell in the box to be covered by exactly one cube in $C$.

For $(\ell,w,h)=(5,5,9)$, we have $|C|=377$, and the optimal objective value turns out to be $99$, attained  by using two cubes of side length $4$ (for example, with corners $(2,2,1)$ and $(2,2,5)$, respectively) and $5\cdot5\cdot9 - 2\cdot 4^3 = 225 - 128 = 97$ unit cubes, as suggested by @ThomasAndrews.

Comment: How do you even know what $C_{i,j,k}$ is for a given $i,j,k$, though.  The set-partitioning problem requires that, but I don't see how we have that here.

Comment: @Mike a cube with "smallest" corner $(u,v,w)$ and side length $s$ covers the $s^3$ points $$(i,j,k)\in \{u,\dots,u+s-1\} \times\{v,\dots,v+s-1\} \times\{w,\dots,w+s-1\}.$$

Comment: But. for each such cube [or box] don't we have to find a corner for it?

Comment: Each cube in $C$ can be represented by its "smallest" corner $(u,v,w)$ (the corner with the minimum sum $u+v+w$) and its side length $s$.  There are $|C|=377$ cubes in the $5\times 5\times 9$ example.

Comment: But, for a cube, we are not given its smallest corner--or any corner for that cube for that matter. We have to find it--if we are using it in the box.

Comment: I think what you are missing is that $C$ is the set of all possible cubes that fit in the box, and the binary decision variable $x_c$ indicates whether candidate cube $c\in C$ is actually used or not.  The integer linear programming solver determines an optimal vector $x$.

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I see.

Comment: Amazing answer!